# Test an Apache Airflow DAG while it is already scheduled and running?

Tags: airflow

I ran the following test command:

```
airflow test events {task_name_redacted} 2018-12-12
```

...and got the following output:

```
Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: events.{redacted} 2018-12-12T00:00:00+00:00 [None]>, dependency 'Task Instance Slots Available' FAILED: The maximum number of running tasks (16) for this task's DAG 'events' has been reached.
[2019-01-17 19:47:48,978] {models.py:1556} WARNING - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIXME: Rescheduling due to concurrency limits reached at task runtime. Attempt 1 of 6. State set to NONE.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2019-01-17 19:47:48,978] {models.py:1559} INFO - Queuing into pool None
```

My Airflow is configured with a maximum concurrency of 16. Does this mean that I cannot test a task when the DAG is currently running, and has used all of it's task slots?

Also, it was a little unclear from the docs, but does the `airflow test` actually execute the task, as in if it was a `SparkSubmitOperator`, it would actually submit the job?

Answer (score 4):

While I am yet to reach that phase of deployment where concurrency will matter, the [docs](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg) do give a fairly good indication of problem at hand

1. Since at any point of time just one `scheduler` is running (and [you shouldn't  be running multiple anyways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595535/3679900)), indeed it appears that irrespective of whether the `DAG`-*runs* are  **live**-*runs* or **test**-*runs*, this limit will apply on them collectively. So that is certainly a hurdle.

   > # The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
   >
   > **dag_concurrency = 16**

---

2. But beware that merely increasing this number (assuming you have big-enough *boxes* for hefty `worker`s / multiple `worker`s), several other configurations will have to be tweaked as well to achieve the kind of parallelism I sense you want.

   They are all listed under `[core]` section

   > # The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This
   >   defines the max number of task instances that should run
   >   simultaneously on this airflow installation
   >
   > **parallelism = 32**
   >
   > # When not using pools, tasks are run in the "default pool", whose
   >   size is guided by this config element
   >
   > **non_pooled_task_slot_count = 128**
   >
   > # The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
   >
   > **max_active_runs_per_dag = 16**

---

3. But we are still not there, because once you spawn so many tasks simultaneously, the backend *metadata*-db will start choking. While this is likely a minor problem (and might not be affecting unless you have some real huge `DAG`s / very large no of `Variable` *interactions* in your tasks), its still worth noting as a potential roadblock

   > # The SqlAlchemy pool size is the maximum number of database
   >   connections in the pool. 0 indicates no limit.
   >
   > **sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5**
   >
   > # The SqlAlchemy pool recycle is the number of seconds a connection
   >   can be idle in the pool before it is invalidated. This config does not
   >   apply to sqlite. If the number of DB connections is ever exceeded, a
   >   lower config value will allow the system to recover faster.
   >
   > **sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 1800**
   >
   > # How many seconds to retry re-establishing a DB connection after
   >   disconnects. Setting this to 0 disables retries.
   >
   > **sql_alchemy_reconnect_timeout = 300**

---

4. Needless to say, all this is pretty much futile unless you pick the right `executor`; `SequentialExecutor`, in particular is only intended for testing

   > # The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include SequentialExecutor, LocalExecutor, CeleryExecutor, DaskExecutor,
   >   KubernetesExecutor
   >
   > **executor = SequentialExecutor**

---

5. But then [params to `BaseOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L2357) like `depends_on_past`, `wait_for_downstream` are there to spoil the party as well

---

6. Finally I leave you with this link related to `Airflow` + `Spark` combination: [How to submit Spark jobs to EMR cluster from Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022129/how-to-submit-spark-jobs-to-emr-cluster-from-airflow)

*(Pardon me if the answer confused you more than you already were, but..)*

Comment: So, what's the answer to the question?

Comment: Airflow can sometimes be complicated.